# Wifi networks not showing after installing ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo y50

Tags: drivers, lenovo, broadcom

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 along side windows 10 on my lenovo y50 laptop. The installation finished properly but I cant seem to get the wifi networks to show up. I have spent days trying to do this and have tried almost all relevant posts related to reinstalling the broadcom driver. Can someone please give me advice than can work for my laptop model?

EDIT:
I was asked to add the result for the following commands:

Command:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

Gives

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0623]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

Command:

```
rfkill list all
```

Gives:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
    2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Do you indeed have a Broadcom device? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` And also: `rfkill list all`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I have added the results for the commands you requested. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You've got to install the appropriate drivers for the broadcom device.

Go to the menu and search for drivers. Update the drivers for everything there right now so that you won't have to waste your time some other day on some other issue.

This will most likely allow you to connect to wifi networks

Comment: I already tried that. There is no difference.